# How to represent this set using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to test my list of "opcodes" to see that they coincide with my valid opcodes which are a pair of digits 0-9 which I test in the following way: `var isValidNumericOpcode = (/^[0-9]{2}$/i);` or an opcode that contains a letter (A or D in my example) and a digit or just two letters (A or D in my example).  How would I check for that second case if I were to be looking for anything that matches a set like this for example ["A9", "AD", "8D"] ignoring case (ie any of these would be valid`["A9", "a9", "AD", "aD", "Ad", "ad", "8D", "8d"]`).

Thank you

Comment: @TedHopp since Joey has "A9" i would assume "d8" is valid too.

Comment: no, only (in my example) A9, AD or 8D in that order and case insensitive would be valid opcodes

Comment: @mauris - Per Joey's comment, the take-away is, "don't assume". Joey - It's not clear from your post whether the "examples" are an exhaustive list. If not, it's not clear what's in and what's out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "examples" are an exhaustive list, the easiest is a set of alternatives:

```
/^([0-9]{2}|a[9d]|8d)$/i
```

There are other possible sets of alternatives, but these, I think, cover it.

Comment: that should do it, let me try it with my larger list of opcodes and I will let you know how it works